# ImageList limited to 256x256 bitmaps

Tags: delphi

I want to load two larger images (480x60) in a TImageList. The ImageList will be assigned to a custom control (custom button) that will read the two images.

However, the Width/height of TImageList has a cap at 256. I was not aware of that because I never loaded something else than icons in TImageList.
[image]

Which would be the best/quick alternative (already present in Delphi11)?

Comment: The limitation comes from the underlying Window's ImageList which tops out at 256x256.   The Bonus KSVC 7.0 suite that comes with modern Delphi which you can install using GetIt includes a TRzBmpButton that might be of use.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.VirtualImageList.TVirtualImageList

Comment: @DelphiCoder - Thanks. I am trying now TImageCollection

Comment: @DelphiCoder - It works with TImageCollection. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:
Since I need only two images, I created two **class** TPngImage variables. At run time I need to call only once a procedure to load something in those images, then I am good to go.
Tested. Works. Uses less memory because of the shared image.

Solution 2:
Starting from the TVirtualImageList suggested by DelphiCoder. Use TImageCollection which supports large images.
Tested. Works.

Comment: Include this personal decision in your question instead of making it an answer. It helps nobody else.

Comment: Thanks - putting 3 comments in a row with text that would fit in one perfectly shows your understanding of this website. Interestingly enough most high-score profiles tend to behave like beginners - as if they forget what they once learnt.

Comment: 1. The question does specifically say that only two images are required, and they are for a custom button. My solution perfectly answers the question.
2. My solution is efficient because it uses shared images.
3. This is an open discussion. Anyone else can post an answer (none posted to this point). You are welcome, too, IF you have more than a random (non-technical) ramble to post (since you are talking about the quality of the comments)  :)

Comment: PS: I will accept DelphiCoder's answer if he will post it.